# Reference on analysis of $k$-nearest neighbor density estimation

Tags: references, density-function, k-nearest-neighbour, density-estimation

I am looking for pointers to the analyses of the $k$-nearest neighbor density estimator.

In particular, for a fixed $k$, I would like to find the derivation of the mean and the variance of the KNN estimator at a fixed point in space. I'm interested in relatively small values of $k$ that do not depend on the number of samples.